# How to save the tags in AngularJS on a device?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do you save these tags with AngularJS? Everytime I refresh the page, the tags I add disappear. I've tried local storage but I wasn't able to make it work.

HTML:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/css/ng-tags-input.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
    <script src="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/js/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.tags = [
    { text: 'Tag1' },
    { text: 'Tag2' },
    { text: 'Tag3' }
  ];
});
```

Link: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/demos

Comment: LocalStorage is a good option if you're not able to save anything on a server. Try adding the code you used to get that to work, and someone can help.

Comment: Try [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) but this time make it work (or post here what you tried)